# .NET MVC Model Binding: nothing happen

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello this is my first time with .NET MVC 3

I have  a controller that is supposed to change password for the logged in User:

```
public ActionResult ChangeUserPassword(string userId)
{
    ChangePasswordModel model = new ChangePasswordModel() { Id = userId };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeUserPassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
        // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
        bool changePasswordSucceeded = true;
        try
        {
            changePasswordSucceeded = userDetailsService.ChangeUserPassword(model.Id, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            changePasswordSucceeded = false;
        }

        if (changePasswordSucceeded)
        {
            return View("ChangePasswordSuccess");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.";
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View();
}

public ActionResult ChangePasswordSuccess()
{
    return View();
}
```

The View is the following:

```
@model MVCApp.Models.ChangePasswordModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change User Password";
}

<h2>Change User Password</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Change Password</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OldPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

When I click on the button 'Save', nothing happen.
Can you either suggest me if I am doing something wrong or how to catch and display the error?

Edit: Debugger does not find any error when I submit the form

Edit: (picture removed as not relevant)

I have changed the controller:

```
if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                {
                    return View("ChangePasswordSuccess");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("ChangePasswordFailed");
                }
```

but it does not redirect me anywhere... I really don't understand what happens

**EDIT**: I think the model is empty

Comment: Try debugging to catch the error.

Comment: are you able enter in Action Method ?

Comment: What causes the confirmation dialog box to appear and what happens if you disable it?

Comment: @KeithBloom I have no idea: it is not in the Model definition or in the controller, I think it's from Firefox, because it does not appear in Chrome... Nothing happens either ways

Answer (score 1):

mention your action and control in BeginForm.

```
@Html.BeginForm("action","controller", FormMethod.Post);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect it may be Firefox doing it (that dialog popup), try using Chrome. While in Chrome navigate to the page you're trying to debug, and before you hit [Submit] hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools, and switch to the Network Tab. After that open switch pack to the page and hit submit,  make sure you see an entry in there where it tries to contact the server. If it does you can debug the problem in the action on the server, if nothing shows in the Network tab then it's likely something with the client side validation thinks it's not valid and is preventing it from submitting to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing your `model` as overload to your View in your controllers action incase you have any model errors.

```
If(ModelState.IsValid)
{
     //your code
}
else
{
    return View(model);//You did not pass this 
}
```

Also in your view you never used `ViewBag.Message` to see whether your `changePasswordSucceeded` has failed. As you said the controller doesnot show anything it can fail.

You should use `@ViewBag.Message` in your view to check if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try.  See if anything breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question as I found the problem now: the code was correct, the problem was in the Action link that was not sending a proper **UserId** to the Controller.

I found the problem by passing `ViewBag.Message = UserId` to the **View**, so I realised that it was empty.
Fixed

Comment: Make sure you decorate your Models with validation attributes to help capture problems like this. Or if there is no model, but you are using primitive types, check them at the start of your action method and add entries to the ModelState collection using ModelState.AddModelError()`